# Remove a SQLite string value from my table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a column in my SQLite table named 'img_name'. An example of data in that column: **'/storage/extSdCard/img1.jpg /storage/extSdCard/img2.jpg   /storage/extSdCard/pic3.jpg'**. Lets say I wanted to delete an image. I would delete the corresponding word(path). Only problem is, I do not know how to delete a specific word(path) from that column.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to "delete a specific word" is to update the existing value.

So you will need an `UPDATE` statement which selects the appropriate rows, and changes the value of the column. The new value will have to be "computed" from the old value, as you would do in a programming language, using string functions.

```
UPDATE column1
SET column1 = trim(replace(column1||' ','/storage/extSdCard/img2.jpg ',''))
WHERE column2 = 'example'
```

Note that this is an example only. The correct string manipulation required may be different. Your question does not specify your exact requirements.
Please consult the SQLite documentation and internet articles for details of string functions in SQLite.

*Note that this would not be necessary if you didn't store more than one value in a column in each row*.

Answer (score 0):

You should get id of your string that you need to remove, and then pass it in to this:

```
public void deleteById(int id)
        {  
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        String[] position =new String[]{id+""};
        db.delete("img_name", "id=?", position );
    }
```

Note: "id=?". Replace "id" in this statement by your id column